# Django restframework browsable api login with ouath

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a sample api by using djangorestframework which worked fine and I could use browsable api without any problem. Then I added outh2 authentication as mentioned on official website which also worked fine. I can use following to get access token.

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD" http://localhost:8000/oauth2/access_token/
```

I can also use curl to browse my api by using access token.

But while using browsable api I can't browse my api due to obvious reason that browsable api is neither getting any access token nor using any. I think I need to have login for this. So I am not getting where can I customise the current login I am having to use oauth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web browsers don't generally let you set custom headers, so there's no way you can provide your OAuth token.

In general, if you want to use the browsable API then you need to allow session based (i.e. cookie based auth).

You can allow both authentication methods, perhaps restricting session auth for development if that's necessary.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using Django REST Framework and ran into this exact same problem when I installed Django OAuth Toolkit to work alongside it. To fix this, open your settings.py and ensure you add `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` into your "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES" entry found under "REST_FRAMEWORK". It should look something like...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

With this setting in place, you should be able to view your browsable APIs, and even perform POST requests by logging in using Django's session authentication.

Comment: Wow. that saved my life. Can't believe I spent so much time on testing all kinds of different settings and orders of different authentications ..